# python - How to deploy Flask+Gunicorn+Nginx+supervisor on a cloud server?

Tags: nginx, python, deployment, gunicorn, flask

I've read a lot of instructions since yesterday about this issue but all of them have similar steps. However I followed step by step but still can't get everything Ok.

Actually I can make Flask+Gunicorn+supervisor working but Nginx is not working well.

I connect my remote cloud server with SSH and I'm not deploying the site on my computer.

Nginx is installed correctly because when I visit the site via the domain name (aka. `example.com`) it shows the Nginx welcome page.

I use `supervisor` to start Gunicorn and the configuration is

```
[program:myapp]
command=/home/fh/test/venv/bin/gunicorn -w4 -b 0.0.0.0:8000 myapp:app
directory=/home/fh/test
startsecs=0
stopwaitsecs=0
autostart=false
autorestart=false
stdout_logfile=/home/fh/test/log/gunicorn.log
stderr_logfile=/home/fh/test/log/gunicorn.err
```

here I bind the server to port **8000** and **I don't actually know what does 0.0.0.0 stand for but I think it doesn't mean the localhost because I can visit the site via *http://example.com:8000* and it works well.**

Then I tried to use Nginx as a proxy server.

I deleted `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default' and '/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default/` and created `/etc/nginx/sites-available/test.com` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/test.com` and symlink them.

`test.com`

```
server {
        server_name www.penguin-penpen.com;
        rewrite ^ http://example/ permanent;
}

# Handle requests to example.com on port 80
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name example.com;

        # Handle all locations
        location / {
                # Pass the request to Gunicorn
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;

                # Set some HTTP headers so that our app knows where the request really came from
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }
}
```

To my understanding, what Nginx do is when I visit `http://example.com` it passes my request to `http://example.com:8000`.

I'm not quite sure that I should use `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000` here because I don't know whether should Nginx pass the request to localhost **But I 've tried to change it to `0.0.0.0:8000` but it still doesn't work.**

Can anyone help?

Comment: can you connect to http://localhost:8000 ?

Comment: Yes, I can connect directly to port 8000.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` with listen means that gunicorn listens to port 8000 on all IP addresses the computer has. Did you restart nginx after changing configuration? What exactly happens when you connect with browser?

Answer (score 0):

What nginx does is for the location / will pass the request to the proxy_pass value. In this case will send the request to http://127.0.0.0:8000 meaning your gunicorn has to listen on that interface.  Usually gunicorn listens on localhost such as

```
 gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:8000 myapp:app
```

That is because you don't want external users to connect to gunicorn directly but rather trough nginx.

This is a sample nginx conf that works fine with gunicorn started as above

```
   location / {
    proxy_read_timeout 120;
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
```